# dbt-expectations column_type timestamptz test improperly fails

Tags: dbt

Using a sql file

```
SELECT 
    holiday::text
    , observed::date
    , NOW()::timestamptz updated_at
FROM {{ ref('seed_holidays') }}
```

Upon `dbt run -s stage` (where `stage` is the model/schema) I get as expected a timestamptz column in the corresponding table (stg_holidays) with value like `'2023-07-23 14:37:29.060 +1000'`, and inspecting the data_type via DBeaver confirms it's type `timestamptz`.

Next, running `dbt test -s stage`, with a spec in the model stg_schema.yml:

```
- name: stg_holidays
    description: "Victorian State Holidays"
    columns:
      - name: holiday
        tests:
          - not_null
          - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
              column_type: text
      - name: observed
        tests:
          - not_null
          - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
              column_type: date
      - name: updated_at
        tests:
          - not_null
          - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
              column_type: timestamptz
```

I get an error:

> Failure in test
> dbt_expectations_expect_column_values_to_be_of_type_stg_holidays_updated_at__timestamptz
> (models/stage/stg_schema.yml)
> Got 1 result, configured to fail if != 0
>
> compiled Code at target/compiled/[proj_name]/models/stage/stg_schema.yml/dbt_expectations_expect_column_[hash].sql

Running the test query at the path given is pretty useless:

```
with relation_columns as (

        
        select
            cast('HOLIDAY' as TEXT) as relation_column,
            cast('TEXT' as TEXT) as relation_column_type
        union all
        
        select
            cast('OBSERVED' as TEXT) as relation_column,
            cast('DATE' as TEXT) as relation_column_type
        union all
        
        select
            cast('UPDATED_AT' as TEXT) as relation_column,
            cast('TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE' as TEXT) as relation_column_type
        
        
    ),
    test_data as (

        select
            *
        from
            relation_columns
        where
            relation_column = 'UPDATED_AT'
            and
            relation_column_type not in ('TIMESTAMPTZ')

    )
    select *
    from test_data
```

Obviously this returns
| relation_column | relation_column_type |
| --------------- | -------------------- |
| UPDATED_AT | TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE |

The same thing happens with just timestamp type.

**Why do these timestamp and timestamp columns fail dbt-expectations tests?**

Comment: Meta: the markdown table in the above looks perfect in draft, but renders badly in the published version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer only occurred to me while documenting for the question, but I thought I'd post question and answer to save others the irritation.

for `timestamptz` (under postgresql) the dbt-expectations test has to be

```
  - name: stg_holidays
    columns:
      ...
      - name: updated_at
        tests:
          - not_null
          - dbt_expectations.expect_column_values_to_be_of_type:
              column_type: timestamp with time zone
```

or `column_type: timestamp without time zone` for `timestamp`.

This hadn't jumped out at me in combing the dbt-expectations docs, but it does solve the problem.